# How to pin openssh from eoan in bonic

Tags: server, package-management, ssh, repository, openssh

I want to pin **only** "openssh-server" package from eoan to my current bionic distro which has an old openssh version.

Comment: Do you already have the newer version installed, and just want to pin it?

Comment: @OrganicMarble no I don't have it installed. I just need the instructions for pinning only the "openssh-server" package.